# send Ctrl-S to browser in Capybara Webkit test

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, webkit, capybara

I have JavaScript in my application that submits a form when the user hits Ctrl-S or Cmd-S. I want to write an automated test for this using RSpec, Capybara, and Capybara Webkit. I don't think I can just have Capybara execute JavaScript to trigger Ctrl-S/Cmd-S because that's not normally allowed with JavaScript in Chrome as a security concern. I see with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365217/testing-jquery-selectable-capybara-or-selenium-ctrl-click) there are `page.driver.browser.action.key_down`/`key_up` methods available. Is there anything similar with Capybara Webkit? If not, how can I send Ctrl-S and Cmd-S to the browser in my test?

**Edit:** I also can't get this to work using the regular Selenium driver with Firefox:

```
describe 'edit a template and hit Ctrl-S', js: true do
  render_views

  it 'saves the template' do
    visit my_path
    page.execute_script("$('#hidden_textarea').val('Fabulous new content')")
    builder = page.driver.browser.action
    builder.key_down(:control).send_keys('s').key_up(:control).perform
    expect(page).to have_text('Record was saved.')
    expect(page).to have_text('Fabulous new content')
  end
end
```

It looks like the `builder.key_down(:control).send_keys('s').key_up(:control).perform` isn't doing anything--the page loads in Firefox but just sits there. This is with Firefox 19 on OS X with selenium-webdriver 2.35.1.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work in either Firefox or Chrome, with either Selenium or Capybara Webkit?

Comment: By the way, the JavaScript I'm trying to test does work. When Selenium opens Firefox, if I wait a second and hit Ctrl-S myself, the form submits as expected and the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do a similar thing in Chrome using Capybara and SitePrism. This actually works for me in Firefox though:

```
page.element.native.send_keys :command, 'a'
```

so I suggest trying this

```
builder.native.send_keys :control, 's'
```